# Xamarin C# - Create a swipeable LinearLayout

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, android-linearlayout

I created a LinearLayout 1, but I also need to show LinearLayout 2. The problem was that it would take a lot of space on the screen, so I thought that I could make it swipeable.

Now I need to create a swipeable view, but I can't find anything about swiping between LinearLayouts. So just to be clear, I need some kind of slide show for LinearLayouts... Does someone know how I can create something like that or can provide me with an example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could achieve it by [ViewPager](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/user-interface/controls/view-pager/).
ViewPager is a layout manager that lets you implement gestural navigation. Gestural navigation allows the user to swipe left and right to step through pages of data.

This is rendering.

[image]

Plese refer to the following code.

activity_main.axml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/viewpager_page"
/>
```

view_one.axml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="first Page"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
/>
```

view_Two.axml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="second Page"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
/>
```

MainActivity.cs

```
namespace ViewPager
{
[Activity(Label = "@string/app_name", Theme = "@style/AppTheme", MainLauncher = true)]
public class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity
{
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.activity_main);
        Android.Support.V4.View.ViewPager viewpager_page = FindViewById<Android.Support.V4.View.ViewPager>(Resource.Id.viewpager_page);
        List<View> viewlist =new List<View>();
        //LayoutInflater.Inflate;
        viewlist.Add(LayoutInflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.view_one,null,false));
        viewlist.Add(LayoutInflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.view_Two, null, false));
        MyPagerAdapter mAdapter = new MyPagerAdapter(viewlist);
        viewpager_page.Adapter = mAdapter;
    }
}
}
```

MyPagerAdapter .cs

```
class MyPagerAdapter : PagerAdapter
{
    List<View> viewlist;
    public MyPagerAdapter(List<View> viewlist)
    {

        this.viewlist = viewlist;
    }
    public override int Count => 2;

    public override bool IsViewFromObject(View view, Java.Lang.Object @object)
    {
        return view == @object;
    }

    public override Java.Lang.Object InstantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position)
    {
        container.AddView(viewlist[position]);
        return viewlist[position];
    }
    public override void DestroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Java.Lang.Object @object)
    {
        container.RemoveView(viewlist[position]);
    }
}
```